# Непонятный перенос строки

Tags: строки

Здраствуйте.
Не пойму в чем проблема.

```
preg_match_all('|<li[^\>\<]+>(.+)</li>|Us',$detailsText[1],$details,PREG_SET_ORDER);
for($i=0; $i<count($details); $i++){
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test/'.$i);
  $text.="\r\n<b>".$details[$i][0]."</b>\r\n".curl_exec($curl)."\r\n";
}
```

Получается что сначала выдает с curl_exec а после <b>что-то</b>

Уж извините за возможно глупый вопрос.
Спасибо.

Comment: С file_get_contents все как надо, нету переносов  на перед. Но курл нужно(

Comment: Так наверно правильнее:  

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test/'.$details[$i][0]);